# Button's OnClick handler can't decide if or what it wants to override

Tags: android, android-intent, android-button

I can get the following to compile (by commenting out the "@Override"):

```
Button buttonAuthorizeUsers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAuthorizeUsers);
buttonAuthorizeUsers.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    //@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent configure = new  Intent(OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity.this, Configure_Activity.class);  
        OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity.this.startActivity(configure); 
    }
  });
```

...but it causes my app to crash. When I comment out it runs fine (but I have no button handler).

Should the class have a "implements OnClickListener"? It seems like I should, but it compiles without it, and won't compile WITH it (whether I comment out the "override" or not, it's unhappy).

Comment: check your imports....for proper OnClickListener.

Answer (score 2):

as per my suggestion, it is not good to remove `@Override` line. you need to change to JDK version in your eclipse then you will not get such errors. Follow, following steps for it,

Right Click on your Project & select Properties.

Then from the left section Select Java Compiler & select the Version of the JDK you installed. If it is already selected then de-select it & try it.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it made no difference. Somehow it had reverted back to 1.5 from 1.6 (I changed it a month or so ago when I had a problem). Re-changing to 1.6 did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Dont remove @Override. just replace

```
setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

with `setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

and also replace `implements OnClickListener` with `implements View.OnClickListener` in your class declaration line.

save and then compile . your problem will get solved.